# convex function $f(x,y)=e^{\alpha x^2+2y^2}-1$

Tags: real-analysis

I have to study if $f(x,y)=e^{\alpha x^2+2y^2}-1$ is convex or not in its domain.If I calculate the Hessian matrix I have problem to define for which $\alpha$ is convex (only for $\alpha =0$ the Hessian is semi-positive definite).
But is $f(x,y)=e^{\alpha x^2+2y^2}$ ever a convex function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If f and g are convex functions and g is non-decreasing , then $h(x)=g(f(x))$ is convex.  Taking $g(x)=e^x$  which is non-decreasing and convex, you have that $h(x)=e^{f(x)}$ is convex if $f(x)$ is convex. In your case you have to find a value of $\alpha$ such that $f(x,y)=\alpha x^2+2y^2$ is convex.

Hint 2: Remember that the sum of two convex (concave) functions is convex (concave).

Comment: why $g(x)=e^x $ is non-decreasing?

Comment: The exponential function is monotonic increasing. Take the derivative and note that it's always positive.

Comment: Can I use the same principle to study convexity of f(x,y)=$\int_{0}^{x^2+y^4} e^{t^2}dt$?

Comment: give a look to the "Leibniz rule".https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: I have to calculate the partial derivatives for the Hessian matrix?